# Cambiar el idioma de la fecha en Jasper Reports

Tags: date, jasper-reports, idioma

Tengo una base de datos Oracle XE, de la cual extraigo información para un reporte, el cual en modo de desarrollo muestra la fecha en español, sin embargo al momento que lo ejecuto desde mi aplicación en Oracle Apex pone la fecha en inglés.

¿Alguna sugerencia de como cambiar la fecha?

Gracias y saludos

Comment: Pon algo de código, como muestras la información para el reporte, entre ellas la fecha

Comment: En un campo de tipo Texto dentro del reporte pongo la siguiente expresión: "MEXICO A  " + $F{FECHA_ACTUAL} el valor de FECHA_ACTUAL lo recupero de una consulta en la base de datos XE, en el lado del cliente me devuelve MEXICO A LUNES 17 DE JULIO DE 2017, lo cual es correcto y cuando lo ejecuto desde el lado de la aplicación devuelve MEXICO A MONDAY 17 DE JULY DE 2017, es decir coloca el mes y el día en inglés. Lo que necesito es que se muestre en español. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Con la instrucción `Locale` le especificas el lenguaje que quieres utilizar en este caso español **"es"** ingles por ejemplo seria **"us"**.

```
(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy hh:mm aaa",new Locale("es", "ES"))).format(new Date())
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución NLS_LANGUAGE

```
SELECT ENAME FROM EMP
WHERE HIREDATE > TO_DATE('1-JAN-01','DD-MON-YY',
'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = AMERICAN')
```

e.g. NLS_LANGUAGE = "MEXICAN SPANISH" para México

O si tienes acceso como SYS

```
Run ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE="MEXICAN SPANISH";
```